# Не удается создать меню в Android Studio

Tags: android

Являюсь новичком в программировании. Пытаюсь создать простецкое меню в android studio, но при попытке создать его оно не отображается в эмуляторе, не знаю, в чем проблема. Делаю в точности все, как описано в инструкции.

**код main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_other"
        android:title="@string/test_other"
        android:onClick="onClickMenuOption"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_exit"
        android:title="Exit"
        android:onClick="onClickMenuExit"/>
</menu>
```

**код MainActivity.java:**

```
package com.examples.nick.testmenu;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    public void onClickMenuOption(MenuItem item) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "You Clicked on Other", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
    }
    public void onClickMenuExit(MenuItem item) {
        finish();
    }
}
```

При запуске эмулятора получаю белое окно с надписью "HelloWorld!" без всякого меню. ((

Answer (score 2):

Если совсем по-простому то можно переопределить метод  `onCreateOptionsMenu` для создания и метод `onOptionsItemSelected` для обработки кнопок меню:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  menu.add("menu1");
  menu.add("menu2");
  menu.add("menu3");
  menu.add("menu4");

  return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  Toast.makeText(this, item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}   }
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, решение оказалось проще: Overflow menu скрыто в NavigationBar в телефонах, у которых имеется кнопка "Menu", и активируется соответственно при нажатии на кнопку "Menu", это актуально для версии до 4.4.2 Kit-Kat. Для версий старше идет Action Bar с Action overflow.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.menu_other) {
        return true;
    }

    if (id == R.id.menu_exit) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

И вместо наследования от `Activity` лучше использовать `AppCompatActivity` в нем вложен `toolbar` и плюс к использованию `materialdesign`

Answer (score 0):

Добавляя `Activity toolbar`, нужно сообщить, что мы его используем вместо `ActionBar`, связано с необходимостью нормальной работы на устройствах со старыми версиями ниже API21. Поэтому, в `Activity onCreate` вызываем метод `setSepportActionBar`. Вот так:

```java
public class UserInfoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // ........................

    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // ....................

        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // ..................
    }
}
```